# only round values under 0.5 up in VBS

Tags: vbscript

I need some help on my VBS script.

I use this for show every 10 percent a status:

```
Max = 300
everyPercent = 10
for x = 1 to Max 
    if x mod Max / 100 * everyPercent = 0 then
        msgbox round((x / Max ) * 100) & "% done" & vbcr & vbcr & "Status: " & x  & "/" & Max 
    end if
next
```

Works great, if the max value is above 5. On 5 the script crashes, because `mod` convert the 2 numbers with `int` and round. So 0.4 changes to 0 and a division of `mod` fails.

Is there an easy way (in the same line) to round always correct, but nothing under 1.

in VB.net i would use this:

```
if x mod (iif((Max / 100 * everyPercent) < 1, 1, Max / 100 * everyPercent) = 0 then
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused as to why this has to be in a single line and a simple

```
If Max / 100 * everyPercent < 1 Then
  temp = 1
Else
  temp = Max / 100 * everyPercent
If x mod temp = 0 Then
...
```

Is not enough but if you are such a fan of inline if why not just create it yourself?

```
Function IIf(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
    If condition Then
        IIf = value_if_true
    Else 
        IIf = value_if_false
    End If
End Function
```

If you create a function like that you can imo use it exaclty like you would an iif.